# How does including an interaction term change interpretation of two deviation coded predictors

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, categorical-encoding

Suppose I am running a regression with two dummy coded dichotomous variables. Unless I am mistaken, the coefficient for IV1 reflects the effect of IV1 *only at* IV2 = 0.

How does this change when the model also includes the IV1 x IV2 interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unless I am mistaken, the coefficient for IV1 reflects the effect of
>   IV1 only at IV2 = 0.

No, the coefficient of IV1 reflects the difference of mean DV associated with change in IV1, *holding IV2 constant*. IV2 can be 0, and IV2 can be 1, as long as it's held constant, the regression coefficient of IV1 captures the mean difference in DV.

When IV1 = 1, the regression formula is:

$$DV_{IV1 = 1} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (1) + \beta_2 (IV2)$$

When IV1 = 0, the regression formula is:

$$DV_{IV1 = 0} = \beta_0 + \beta_2 (IV2)$$

The difference is then:

$$DV_{IV1 = 1} - DV_{IV1 = 0} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (1) + \beta_2 (IV2) - \beta_0 - \beta_2 (IV2)$$

ending with just $\beta_1$. Notice that IV2 can be any number, as long as they are the same number in both scenarios, the IV2 terms are cancelled out.

> How does this change when the model also includes the IV1 x IV2
>   interaction?

For this, your original statement would be correct: the coefficient for IV1 reflects the difference in mean DV associated with of IV1 when IV2 = 0.

$$DV_{IV1 = 1, IV2 = 0} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (1) + \beta_2 (0) + \beta_3 (1 \times 0)$$

$$DV_{IV1 = 0, IV2 = 0} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (0) + \beta_2 (0)+ \beta_3 (0 \times 0)$$

The difference is just $\beta_1$.

When IV2 = 1, then:

$$DV_{IV1 = 1, IV2 = 1} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (1) + \beta_2 (1) + \beta_3 (1 \times 1)$$

$$DV_{IV1 = 0, IV2 = 1} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (0) + \beta_2 (1)+ \beta_3 (0 \times 1)$$

the difference became $(\beta_1 + \beta_3)$